# Homemade capacitor - crafting and testing

Tags: capacitor

I'm a laic when it comes to electronics, but I want to venture myself in creating things with my own hands.

Looking for that, I found a tutorial that teaches how to make a capacitor with foil sheets and wax paper.

I need to know the formulas and all the variables and how I can safely test it to learn it's capacities (no site that I visited showed any of this.)

Comment: All it is, is a parallel plate capacitor rolled up.

Comment: you mean that aluminium is a natural capacitor? if so makes sense. but i still need to know how I extract all the data that i need to work with it :)

Comment: Aluminium is a natural *conductor*: you get two big sheets of it (plates), lie some wax paper between them (dielectric) and roll 'em up like a burrito to make the whole thing more compact. You'll need two sheets of wak paper but I think you got that covered. To calculate the capacitance you should at least know the permittivity of the wax paper...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take two sheets of dielectric (perhaps PET) and two sheets of aluminum foil and roll them into a cylinder you'll get almost double the capacitance of an equivalent area of parallel plate capacitor, because both sides of most of the plates are used.

[image: http://www.antonine-education.co.uk/Image_library/Physics_4/Capacitors/capacitor_const.JPG]

The capacitance is about

C= \$\frac{2\epsilon_0 \epsilon_rA}{t}\$ where

A is the area of the plates (in meters squared)

\$\epsilon_0\$ is the permittivity of free space 8.8E-12 (fundamental constant)

\$\epsilon_r\$  is the dielectric constant of the plastic 3.4 (look this up)
 for wax paper it's similar- 3.7.

t is the thickness of the dielectric in meters (foil thickness does not matter for capacitance, except it makes the capacitor bigger)

You can look up the dielectric strength of the material to get an estimate of the voltage capability (don't get too close to the limit). PET is 400V/mil (1 mil = 0.0254mm). Wax paper is [reportedly](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2007/DashaMulyukova.shtml) 30-40MV/m.

So if you roll up  2m x 0.2m pieces of foil and PET 0.004" thick you'd get a capacitor of capacitance ~240nF good for at least hundreds of volts. You can work it out for the wax paper situation once you know the thickness.

You can safely test it with a capacitance meter after making sure it is discharged. Making the dielectric thinner reduces the voltage capability but increases the capacitance.

Commercial parts use thin plastic dielectric and better techniques- a comparable part would cost a couple dollars and be 18mm x 12mm x 15mm. They would also be a better part electrically because they would connect to the edges of the foil so the parasitic inductance would be less.

Comment: i forgot to mention that in one of the videos was used candle wax to seal the top and bottom. is there other substances that i can use in the place of the candle wax (for it is flammable and i don't want my project on fire :P), or even necessary to seal the top and bottom of the capacitor?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt, if only for mechanical stability. Most types of glues could work, and epoxy would be great. If you're going to be putting hundreds of volts in it, best to provide as much protection as possible. Note that shorting a capacitor's leads creates physical force between it's plates (after all, it's essentially static electricity in there, and like-charges repel.)

Comment: P.S. here is a great series of texts about electronics. http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/